# Is there a method for jQuery .tmpl() completed event handling?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

I'd like to ask, how can i make a $.tmpl ready function?

In my code I pass the ajax json to my createForm function.

```
var doFunction = {
new: function() { 
    $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php?...',
      success: function(data) {
        createForm(data).appendTo($("#whitespace"));
        $("#whitespace").click(function(){
            $(this).empty().hide();
        });
        $("#popup").click(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $("#whitespace").show();
      }
    });
},
```

The createForm function

```
function createForm(data) {
var $container = $('<div id="popup"></div>');
var $content = $('<article></article>');
$.get('mydomain.com/formcreator.htm', function(template) {
  $.tmpl(template, data).appendTo($content);
});
$content.appendTo($container);
return $container;
}
```

But if I tell the `$container` to `$container.find(".tabs").tabs();` - it contains an `<div class="tabs>...etc...</div>`.

I think the problem is I did not catched the $.tmpl finish event.
Is there a success event of the $.tmpl?

Please help me in this.

Comment: I don't think that `tmpl` is the real problem here as  I think the function is synchronous.  Instead, try to use `$container.find` in the callback function for `$.get` after the template has been applied. By the way, it would help, if you would show us when the `$container.find` was called when it failed.

Comment: The $.get is asyncronous. I've tried it after the `success: function(data) {...` in a `complete: function...` but the same problem occurs :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @Aleksi Yrttiaho for this, the solution is turning off the asynchronous ajax request, and use synchronous instead of it.

```
$.ajax({ url: 'domain.com/formcreator.htm',
success: function(template) {
    $.tmpl(template, data).appendTo($content);
},
async: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
success: function(data) {
        createForm(data).appendTo($("#whitespace"));
        $.fn.ready(function(){
            //your append callback function
        });
}
```

It works nicely for me.